# Results from query to SQL database not showing until temporary internet files deleted

Tags: php, javascript, sql

I have two webpages. The first allows the user to change the department that a teacher belongs to. The action from the button calls `php` file which sends the required `SQL` command and the information is added to the `SQL` database correctly.

[image: first page]

The second then displays two drop down boxes. When the department is selected the second drop down lists the teachers in that department.

[image: webpage2]

To get this data I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTeacherList(departmentName, schoolName) 
{
var xmlhttp;

if (departmentName=="All")
  {
//  document.getElementById("departmentTeachers").innerHTML="";
    $("#departmentTeachers").hide(0);
    $("#allTeacherList").show(0);
  return;
  }
 else
{ 
    $("#departmentTeachers").show(0);
    $("#allTeacherList").hide(0);

} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("departmentTeachers").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+departmentName,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If I add a teacher to a department from the first page it is only displayed in the second page if I manually delete the Temporary Internet files.

I realise that the old data is being cached but I am not sure how force a reload so that the data is displayed correctly?

Comment: you can add a random value to the end of your query string like `&t=math.Random()` to make the query string unique every time you call it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to append a random value to the query string like the current time

```
var d = new Date();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/iobserve/php/getTeachers.php?schoolName="+schoolName+"&departmentName="+departmentName+"&nocache="+d.getSeconds(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

or set a header

```
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT");
```

or set the cache headers on the server side

```
 header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT");
 header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s")."GMT");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

[Controlling cache](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#How_will_caching_be_controlled.3F)